# Is there a way to prevent a div from falling under another div when shrinking browser size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have div which has row-fluid class and within it are two divs which are side by side. When I reduce the window size I can see the right div go under the left one. I am pretty new to bootstrap and css. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: any code or image ?

Comment: @ReynaldHenryleo please ask for code. Images are also didn't accepted without code.

Comment: There is a way. But I won't make an answer unless you put the code.

Comment: yeah, it would help big time to see how they're overlapping!! use codepen.com or jsfiddle.com or plnkr.co to show us a demo of the problem